# IConfigurationRoot and Unity

Tags: c#, .net-core, unity-container

I have a .NET Core Contsole app which also uses some library.
So I added to the Unity container my library:

```
_container = new UnityContainer();
_container.RegisterType<ILib, Lib>();
```

The problem is that the Lib takes IConfigurationRoot in the constructor, which later I use to get the connection string.
And I am having a problem of how to properly register IConfigurationRoot in the unity container.

I have a private method with the following code:

```
  var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
    Configuration = builder.Build();
```

I also tried to put this code into another class: Class1, inherited from IClass1 with the IConfig property, then I tried to register them in the cntainer and it did not work.

Please advise.

Comment: `_container.RegisterInstance(Configuration);` ?

Comment: No, it does not work

Comment: Could you please share what is exact problem?

Comment: I don't have the exact exception but it says that it can't create the instance of class from ILib. ILib is fine, I can create it if I remove this constructor parameter

Comment: Unity exceptions have detailed messages with exact reason why the instance could not be created. The first thing to do - examine the exception message.